# How to change hitTest area in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Somebody knows how to change hitTest area in Flutter?

I have RenderObject and I want to paint child in other place inner my widget.
I changed paint offset and add new hitTest area with help `BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset`
But I don't want hitTest to trigger on a child widget with old coordinates 0,0;50,50

Below is an example of my code

```
class BottomPanel extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final Widget? child;

  BottomPanel([this.child]) : super(child: child);

  @override
  BottomPanelRenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) =>
      BottomPanelRenderObject();
}

class BottomPanelRenderObject extends RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior {
  BottomPanelRenderObject() : super(behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent);

  final newChildOffset = Offset(0, 100);

  @override
  Rect get paintBounds => Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 200, 400);

  @override
  void layout(Constraints constraints, {bool parentUsesSize = false}) {
    super.layout(constraints, parentUsesSize: parentUsesSize);
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    final hitTestResult = super.hitTest(result, position: position);
    print('hitTest: hitTestResult=$hitTestResult BoxHitTestResult=${result}');
    if (child != null) {
      final childHitTest = result.addWithPaintOffset(
        offset: newChildOffset,
        position: position,
        hitTest: (result, offset) {
          return child!.hitTest(result, position: offset);
        },
      );
      print('childHitTest: BoxHitTestResult=${childHitTest}');
    }
    return hitTestResult;
  }

  @override
  void setupParentData(covariant RenderObject child) {
    super.setupParentData(child);
  }

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    print('performLayout');
    size = paintBounds.size;

    child?.layout(constraints, parentUsesSize: true);
  }

  @override
  void performResize() {
    print('performResize');
    size = paintBounds.size;
  }

  void paintBox(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    context.canvas
      ..drawRect(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 150, 100, 100),
        Paint()..color = Colors.blueGrey,
      );
  }

  void paintChild(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child != null) {
      context.paintChild(child!, offset);
    }
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    context.pushLayer(
      OffsetLayer(
        offset: newChildOffset,
      ),
      paintChild,
      offset,
    );
    layer = context.pushClipRect(
      needsCompositing,
      offset,
      paintBounds,
      paintBox,
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    );
  }
}
```

[Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RVfg.jpg)

Read the flutter docs

Answer (score 0):

That's resolved my problem

```
 @override
  bool hitTestChildren(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    final parentData = child?.parentData as BottomPanelParentData?;
    if (parentData != null) {
      final childHitTest = result.addWithPaintOffset(
        offset: parentData.offset,
        position: position,
        hitTest: (result, offset) {
          return child!.hitTest(result, position: offset);
        },
      );
      return childHitTest;
    }
    return false;
  }
```